# why to put curly braces in USING statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, using

when and why to put curly braces with USING statement in Asp.net(C#) ?

e.g.

```
 using (Log L = new Log())
{
       ...
}
```

why and when to put curly braces ? benefits ? And what is the difference between USING and using that we use to include namespace in source code e.g.

```
using system.net
```

1 more thing, last thing, as it says that USING statement automatically implements TRY CATCH then why always coders put try catch inside using ? E.g.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom))
{
    try
    {
        //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
        sqlDA.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
        return ds;

    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        Response.Write(se.Message);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `using` to include namespaces (`using System.Net`) is a [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sf0df423.aspx) (vs a [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx))

Comment: A using statement does not automatically implement a try catch block, all using will do is it will call dispose on the object declared in the using statement, when the code exits the block. Yes it may be the equivalent of a try finally block, but it will not perform a try catch, these are very different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything inside the {} has access to `L`. Without the {}'s, only the next statement would have access.

It's standard C# syntax, just like putting {}'s after an `if`, `for` or `while` statement for example. It defines a block of code that applies to the `using` statement.

Whilst it uses the same word as an import `using`, it's use is very different. The C# language designers try to reuse reserved words, rather than introducing new ones, for backward compatibility reasons.

In the case of a `using block`, as you are defining, the idea is that the object `L` only exists whilst the using block is executed. It is then disposed afterwards. This saves having to remember to close files or connections and generally tidy up, the using block does that for you.

A using block is in fact just "syntactic sugar" for a try/finally block. As explained at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

Comment: great,, awesome, i tip my hat to you (Y)

Comment: ok so every object from ado.net needs to be disposed ? like SQLCONNECTION, SQLCOMMAND ?

Comment: Anything that implements IDisposable needs to be disposed. Check the   documentation for a class to see if it applies.

Comment: ok 1 last thing, as it says that USING statement automatically implements TRY CATCH then why always coders put try catch inside using ?  E.g.


using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom))
    {
        try
        {
            //sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sqlDA.Fill(ds,"Login");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("DT_CR");
            sqlDA.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            return ds;

        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            Response.Write(se.Message);
            return null;
        }

Comment: @Hunain It is syntactic sugar for a `try { } finally { dispose }`, it doesn't catch anything. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx for details.

Answer (score 6):

As in all other cases in C#. Curly braces are needed if you have multiple lines inside the using

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, `using system.net` is just a [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librAry/sf0df423.aspx) for aliasing and to allow us to reference types without having to quantify it with the full namespace

On the other hand the below is [syntactical sugar for a try/finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librAry/yh598w02.aspx) to guarantee that `Dispose` is called on a type that implements IDisposable

```
using (Log L = new Log())
{
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question it really just saves time, and in some cases help to make things less ambiguous. What I mean by that is I could specify an image as:

```
System.Drawing.Image
```

or

```
ImageMagickNET.Image
```

That's just one example of a namespace that would be imported. So if I knew that all of my images were going to be ImageMagickNET type I would declare the using/imports for the namespace and then instead of:

```
ImageMagickNET.Image
```

I would just say:

```
Image
```

Whenever I needed to reference the class.

Hope that helps!

Comment: great, (Y)

just check my edit to answer 3rd part, last thing to ask actually :)

Comment: Because there's a lot of times where the catch can be used for debugging and catching specific exceptions, an example would be logging or notifying a user of the specific error. You don't always just want to continue on your way.